# WordPress Subcategory Creates 2 urls for same page (serious issue)

Tags: urls, errors, content, post-duplication

All subcategories in WordPress create 2 urls to same page.

**domain.com/parentcat/childcat/**

**domain.com/childcat/**

both urls go to the same page.
in the eyes of Google this is duplicate content.

it seems it would be logical for WordPress
to redirect domain.com/childcat/ to domain.com/parentcat/childcat/

Using WordPress 4.3 no plugins.

I can't seem to find a fix for this anywhere.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This can get a bit demanding to get it right so this following snippet should provide the basic upon which you can research and build a more complete solution:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    if ( is_category() ) {      
        $term = get_queried_object();

        if ( isset( $term->parent ) && $term->parent ) {
            global $wp;

            $request_url = trailingslashit( get_site_url( get_current_blog_id(), $wp->request ) );
            $link = get_term_link( $term );

            if ( ! is_wp_error( $link ) ) {
                if ( strpos( $request_url, trailingslashit( $link ) ) !== 0 ) {
                    wp_safe_redirect( $link, 301 ); 
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
} );
```

This solution will work with pagination too but it will redirect to the start of pagination in case you are attempting to access an "incorrect" sub-category paged URL (`http://www.example.com/category/child/page/2/` will redirect to `http://www.example.com/category/parent/child/` -- this can be addressed by checking if we have a paginated request and build the redirect link accordingly)